# Yellow background with borderRadius

Tags: react-native

In my React Native application I add a `borderRadius` to my `View` component. Sometimes, there is a yellow background, even if I set `backgroundColor:'transparent'` to the view.

[image: RN background]

It disappears if I start scrolling. Is this issue known and is there a solution how I could fix that behavior?

This is how I render of my message components:

```
   <View
     style={styles.ownView}>
      <Text style={[styles.text,styles.ownText]}>{this.props.doc.text}</Text>
      <Image source={require('../../images/chat_own.png')}
       style={{right:0,bottom:5,position:'absolute'}}/>
   </View>



var styles = StyleSheet.create({

ownView: {
    backgroundColor:'transparent',
    flexDirection:'column',
    alignItems:'flex-end',
    marginBottom:15
},

text: {
    color: 'white',
    fontWeight: "200",
    backgroundColor: "#817CD0",
    borderRadius: 12,
    padding: 10,
    right: 0,
    paddingRight: 60
},

ownText: {
    marginRight: 10
 }

});
```

The image is for the bubble part for the right or left side.

Comment: did you use border colour?

Comment: Nope, I didn't set any color or value for the border.

Comment: Check ParentView Style Properties may be your setting somewhere. Post your code so some body can help you:-)

Comment: Can you post the code snippet in RNPlay.org?

Comment: I've updated a code, will later check out RNPlay if I can reproduce it there. At the first sight, I think the problem could be that I've added the radius within the Text element? I did this because the View acts like a block element, but I need an inline behavior.